# get_user_by() return roles as empty array

Tags: wordpress

I get a user with function `get_user_by('login', $user_id)` and the user object returns the `roles` as an empty array.

I check in db table usermeta meta_key wp_capabilities has value:

[image: wp_capabilities]

And also in table option option_name wp_user_roles has the role of user:

[image: wp_user_roles].

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a valid `$user_id`? Note that `$user_id` should be the login name of the user, not the ID associated with the username.

Answer (score 1):

You Want user role from user ID. you can easily get it with using This code .
Try This

```
<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
      echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
?>
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If the function was failing then you'd get a return value of false. Are you sure you're getting an empty array? The documentation specifies that an object is returned, maybe save the result in a variable and var_dump it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
global $wpdb;
$user_roles = get_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities', true );
```

Then you can get role name in array key.

ex:
Array(
[administrator] => 1
)

So that I use array_keys to convert keys to values:

```
$user_roles = array_keys( $user_roles );
```

And now $user_roles same as $current_user->roles